# Does the A380 have more than one auto-brake disengage switch?

Tags: cockpit, airbus-a380, braking

I know that the A380 has low/med/high RTO auto-brakes. What I'm not sure about is if there's a switch near the thrust levers that can disengage the auto-brakes, other than the switches located on the brake panel.

To put it another way, the A380 has a brake panel where the switches allow you to engage/disengage auto-brakes (either low, med, or high RTO). But in addition to those, is there any other switch that can do the same thing without the pilot needing to take his eyes away from the view outside?

Comment: Well, he can tap the breaks.

Comment: @Hugh           yes he can, but it is far more convenient and safe to do it using a button - simply disengages the brake (which already slowed the a/c down significantly, below 50 knt)

Comment: Tapping the brakes is one. Increasing thrust past CLB (for go-around) is another. And does anybody know whether the brakes normally remain on until the aircraft stops or just until it slows down to taxi speed? I'd expect the later (in which case the autobrakes simply disengage themselves in the usual case), but I don't really know.

Comment: If the pilot disarms the Spoilers it will disconnect the auto-brake. Alternatively, the pilot may disengage the auto brake by setting the AUTO BRK Mode selector to DISARM.

Comment: @JanHudec I only have experience with the A319/320, and on those, the autobrake operates until disengaged or the aircraft is stopped. Proper procedure is to take over breaking manually before reaching taxi speed. Although I assume the A380 is the same, I cannot say for sure that it operates the same way.

Comment: @hagubear You can try to find it [here](http://www.airbus.com/fileadmin/backstage/modules/cockpit_airbusA380/flash/cockpit1.htm).

Answer (score 9):

The A380 has one Takeoff Autobrake setting which is RTO and five Landing Autobrake settings which are BTV, LO, 2, 3 and HI. Some may read that as four plus the BTV, which is a variable deceleration compared to fixed deceleration. As you have noted, these are selected from the Autobrake selector switch.

It is possible to disarm the Autobrake using a number of actions. One or two which have been mentioned already.

1. The Autobrake selector switch is set to Disarm.
2. The Brake pedals are depressed with a higher input than the Autobrake setting.
3. The Spoilers are retracted.
4. The Autothrust instinctive disconnect pushbutton switch is pressed. These are located at the ends of the Throttle control levers.
5. The RTO Arm pushbutton switch is set.

FCOM Reference for anyone interested - FCOM/DSC/32/10/30/20/00004244.0002001

Comment: Hello Kamran, welcome to Aviation.SE! Your answer is good as it is, but it could be even better if you would have the FCOM reference for it.

Comment: @DeltaLima Thanks. I am an engineer so I am unaware of the FCOM reference. The ATA reference for anyone interested is 32-42-00 (Normal Braking).

Comment: Having an extra engineer here is even better! Thanks for the reference. DL

Comment: @DeltaLima Thanks for the welcome! Will try and get hold of the FCOM reference after the weekend for anyone interested.

Comment: I found the following reference for anyone interested - FCOM/DSC/32/10/30/20/00004244.0002001